# submit button not working from form display using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form i created using jquery inside different divs element using the same id for the submit button.
**here is part of the jquery code**

```
    //for yahoo mail.
        if(title == "yahoo.com"){
            $("#yahoomailDIV").html("<form><table><tr><td>email:</td><td><input type='text' size='20' name='email'></td></tr><tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type='text' name='number'></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><button id='submitbtn'>Submit</button></td></tr></table></form>");
        }else{
            $("#yahoomailDIV").html("");
    $("#yahoomailDIV").prepend("<img id='gmail_pix' src='images/yahoologo.png' width='250' height='150' alt='gmail'/>")
    }

        //for hot mail.
    if(title == "hotmail.com"){
        $("#hotMailDIV").html("<form><table><tr><td>email:</td><td><input type='text' size='20' name='email'></td></tr><tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type='text' name='number'></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><button id='submitbtn'>Submit</button></td></tr></table></form>");
        }else{
        $("#hotMailDIV").html("");
            $("#hotMailDIV").prepend("<img id='gmail_pix' src='images/hotmail.png' width='250' height='150' alt='gmail'/>")
    }
```

here is the jquery code to know if the button is click

```
    $("button#submitbtn").on("click",function(){
        alert("Hi");
    })
```

here is my html code

```
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
    <div class="mailDiv" id="hotMailDIV" title="hotmail.com"><img src="images/hotmail-logo.png" width="250" height="150" /></div>
    <div class="mailDiv" id="gmailDIV" title="gmail.com"><img src="images/gmail.png" width="250" height="150" /></div>

</div>
<p class="clear"></p>
<div>
    <div class="mailDiv" id="aolmailDIV" title="aol.com"><img src="images/aol.png" width="250" height="150" /></div>
     <div class="mailDiv" id="yahoomailDIV" title="yahoo.com"><img src="images/yahoologo.png" width="250" height="150" /></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="mailDiv" id="othermailDIV" title="othermail" style="margin-left:200px; margin-right:auto"><img src="images/email.png" width="251" height="150" /></div>

</div>
```

my sendMail.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
    $phoneNum = $_POST['number'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fileData = $email."<br/>".$phoneNum;
    $fp = fopen("newFile.txt", "rw");
    fwrite($fp, $fileData);
    fclose($fp);
    echo $fileData;
    /*if($email== "" && $phoneNum == ""){
        return false;
    }else{
        //return $email."<br/>".$phoneNum;
        return true;
    }   */  
}else{
    echo "nothing found";
}
```

?>

the problem am having is that if i click on any of the submit button that is display using jquery, it is not responding at all.
please can anybody help me out here
 thanks
joe

Comment: _"using the same id"_ IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have no compilation errors, try rewritng your click handler to something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#submitbtn",function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Also,you can't use the same id on both of those submit buttons as you'll get an ID conflict.  You can switch it to a class though and it will just require a `.` instead of a `#` in front of submitbtn.

Comment: `$("button").on(', "#submitbtn" ...` is better. not?

Comment: Rooster, just used your suggestion it didn't help and i think since it is diplaying the form individually the id's should not conflict

Comment: @user1496307 with multiple problems pointed out and still no fix you're best bet is to reproduce in and post a jsfiddle

Comment: Rooster, how do you mean please can you give me an example

Comment: @user1496307 visit http://jsfiddle.com and build a fiddle that reproduces your issue.  Then save the fiddle, and post it here for people to solve your issue with.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are generating the form HTML code from a javascript function,
You should register the event:

```
$("button#submitbtn").on("click",function(){
    alert("Hi");
})
```

Only after you added the HTML to the DOM tree in the function that generates the form.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$(".mailDiv").click(function(e){
    if(event.target != this && event.target != $(this).find("img")[0])
        return;
//for yahoo mail.
    if(title == "yahoo.com"){
        $("#yahoomailDIV").html("<form><table><tr><td>email:</td><td><input type='text' size='20' name='email'></td></tr><tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type='text' name='number'></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><button id='submitbtn'>Submit</button></td></tr></table></form>");
    }else{
        $("#yahoomailDIV").html("");
$("#yahoomailDIV").prepend("<img id='gmail_pix' src='images/yahoologo.png' width='250' height='150' alt='gmail'/>")
}

    //for hot mail.
if(title == "hotmail.com"){
    $("#hotMailDIV").html("<form><table><tr><td>email:</td><td><input type='text' size='20' name='email'></td></tr><tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type='text' name='number'></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><button id='submitbtn'>Submit</button></td></tr></table></form>");
    }else{
    $("#hotMailDIV").html("");
        $("#hotMailDIV").prepend("<img id='gmail_pix' src='images/hotmail.png' width='250' height='150' alt='gmail'/>")
}

/*** Add click handler ***/
$("#submitbtn").click(function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
});
```

Comment: please noam do an example for me to see

Comment: I've create an example in jsFiddle, please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/fxLwT/2/

Comment: thank noam, it works but i can't enter anything in the textfield, i have to click and hold then enter text in the textfield but when i release the the mouse button it disappear

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, can you post more of your code? maybe you can create the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can examine it?

Comment: i have create it in http://jsfiddle.net/joedbug/38h3r/1/, please can you check it

Comment: noam i have created it in http://jsfiddle.net/joedbug/38h3r/1/, please take a look at it for me, don't know what is rong with it, thanks

Comment: noam please check that code again cause if i place this code  if(event.target != this)
        return; it doesn't respond at all

Comment: try this: `if(event.target != this && event.target != $(this).find("img")[0])
            return;`     works here: http://jsfiddle.net/38h3r/14/

Comment: The reason why you have to hold down the mouse and type and when you let go the text disappears is because the input is on the mailDiv and the click event bubbles up to the input from the div and your form is getting regenerated, because the click handler is fired. what I'm trying to do is only catch clicks that targeted from the div or bubbled up to the image and ignore click that are targeted from the inputs.

Comment: please can you assist me in finding the solution to this

Comment: actually i don't really know what to do in this case right now

Comment: I asume you are clicking on the image and nothing is happening right? if so, please add the code in the edit above: `if(event.target != this && event.target != $(this).find("img")[0]) return;`

Comment: noam, thanks value can be entered into the text field now, but i have tried submitting it to a form using normal posting to a php page and using jquery but the receiving page is not getting any thing at all, i am going to create it in jsfiddle.net in a moment

Comment: my sendMail.php code<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
  $phoneNum = $_POST['number'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  if($email== "" && $phoneNum == ""){
   return "No Value found";
  }else{
   return $email."<br/>".$phoneNum;
  }  
 }
?>

Comment: noam i have try creating my code in jsfiddle.net but the php code can't be added there so i have added it in my original post

Comment: the data send from the form cannot get to the php page

Comment: noam please do you know why the code is not working in IE and firefox

Comment: Add `<form method="post" action="sendMail.php">`

Answer (score -1):

Edit your jquery code

```
$("button#submitbtn").Click(function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: Raghav, just used your suggestion still it didn't help

Comment: May be your "#submitbtn" id is conflicting. Try with different ids on different submit buttons.